# Can we start session from another php site to wordpress blog site?

Tags: login, authentication

I have created my site in PHP now My Blog site in wordpress so if user logged in PHP site is also logged in Wordpress site it is possible?

Comment: the answer is "yes" if they are no the same domain and "not easy" otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for using below function:

```
    function auto_login() {
        // make sure user is not logged in and "user" was POST'd
        $username = isset( $_POST['user'] )? $_POST['user'] : false;
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $username ){
            // load the user by username
            $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username ); 
            if ( $user ) {
                // log user in using the $user object properties
                wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );
                wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
                do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
            }
        }
    }

add_action( 'wp_loaded','auto_login' );
```

Comment: hmmm, login without checking the password.... is not a real solution just an accident waiting to happen. it doesn't even answer your own question :(

Comment: Not login without password, if user logged in PHP site than this function works.

Comment: you do not check the password anywhere